# as of now it just ignores the if statement and gives them a ticket everytime.php, mysql, If else

Tags: php, mysql

Alright so i'm trying to put value in an array and shuffle them to be random, then have it use that random value in a query. I know my code is bad and not to use `mysql` anymore lets stay off that topic please.
I don't understand why this isn't working I have other things like it that work just fine.
right now it ignores the if statement and gives them a ticket each time.

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    $ticket = array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1");
    shuffle($ticket);

    if ($ticket >= 1) {
        echo "You have Found a Shop Ticket!" ;
        mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ticket=ticket+1 WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") 
            or die(mysql_error());
    } else {
        echo "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you intend `($ticket >= 1)` to mean?

Comment: What is `$ticket >= 1` supposed to do? `$ticket` is an array, not a number.

Comment: If you want the user to have 8% chances of getting that ticket, wouldn't it be easier to just check if `mt_rand(1, 8) === 1` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking if the entire array is >= 1, which is obviously TRUE all the time.

Pick a value instead:

```
$ticket = array_shift($ticket); // do this after you shuffle
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
if (current(shuffle($ticket)) >= 1) {
    # yay
} else {
    # ney
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$ticket is an array, not a number.
u could use foreach or array_map to do this.
example:

```
function foo($n){
    if($n >= 1){//do something}
}
$ticket = array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1");
shuffle($ticket);
array_map('foo', $ticket);
```